# Permission denied for adb shell command

Tags: android, adb

I want to record my android device screen using adb command and I am using the following command.

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/example.mp4
```

I am getting the following error

```
Unable to open '/sdcard/example.mp4': Permission denied
```

Please guide me to resolve this error.

Comment: Try restarting ADB in root mode: `adb root` Also, you could check the permissions for /sdcard/.

Answer (score 0):

There are folders with different access rights.
Try this folder:

```
/storage/sdcard0/Download/
```